# How to call a JavaScript class constructor from Blazor

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

If I have JavaScript classes defined in a library like three.js, how can I call the constructor from Blazor WebAssembly and instantiate objects?

I have tried

```
    var threeJs = await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSInProcessObjectReference>("import", "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r125/build/three.module.js");
    var scn = threeJs.Invoke<IJSInProcessObjectReference>("new THREE.Scene");
```

but this results in an error saying "`Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'new THREE.Scene' ('new THREE' was undefined).`"

Is it possible to instantiate JavaScript classes without making a JavaScript wrapper function which instantiates the object?

Comment: I advise you not to think of JS interop as a means to string together a bunch of separate JS calls.  That's not how it's intended to work.  Create your own custom JS functions in _your_ JS file and have that do the bulk of the work, returning to the Blazor code only what it requires

Comment: IJSObjectReference threeJs; you need to define threeJs first

Comment: You could create a factory function in your JS code and return a new instantiation of the class, then call that function in your C# JsInterop

export class ThreeJsRenderer {

    static Create() {
        return new ThreeJsRenderer();
    }

    constructor(id) {
        // create the scene
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `new THREE.Scene` by itself. You can do something like `const scene = new THREE.Scene`. But, I don't know what good instantiating a variable in JSInterop would do.